# NativeScript Vue ListView onTap not sending item with event

Tags: javascript, ios, listview, nativescript, nativescript-vue

So I have a ListView that's looping through an array objects with an onTap event. The onTap event fires the function it's supposed to, but when I try to console log the event.index or the event.item, as listed in the docs, my app crashes saying:

> "JS ERROR TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'event.index')"

This is the docs I followed: https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/elements/components/list-view/

Here is the relevant markup:

```html
<ListView for="item in feed" @itemTap="onFeedItemTap()" class="background-gray">
  <v-template>
    <StackLayout class="feed-item-panel">
      <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" style="padding: 5">
        <Label class="feed-item" :text="item.Date" row="0" col="0" />
      </StackLayout>
      <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" style="padding: 5">
        <Label class="feed-item bold" :text="'Product: ' + item.Product" fontAttributes="Bold" row="1" col="0" />
      </StackLayout>
      <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" style="padding: 5">                        
        <Label :class="item.mostRecent" :text="item.info" row="2" col="0" textWrap="true" />
      </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>            
  </v-template>
</ListView>
```

relevant JS function:

```js
onFeedItemTap(event) {                
  console.log(event.index);  //GIVES ERROR!!              
  this.$showModal(BBCard);
}
```

Please let me know if there's something I'm missing or at least point me in the right direction. But from the examples, I've viewed, this seems to be the standard procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with {N}, it's purely Vue. In the docs, they do not use parentheses (method event handlers). You get the event object by default here.

```
<ListView for="item in listOfItems" @itemTap="onItemTap">
```

If you use parentheses (method inline handlers) you must use `$event` to give access to event object

```
<ListView for="item in listOfItems" @itemTap="onItemTap($event)">
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize it was like vue where you pass in the event; Worked just like the documentation when I pass in the $event onItemTap.